# if statement is true even if its not when saving ticket

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have maximum number of attendees per event. When storing tickets, it still saves even when the number ordered exceeds the maximum.

`store` function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      // Create Ticket
      $ticket=new Ticket;
      $ticket->userName= $request->input('userName');
      $ticket->userEmail= $request->input('userEmail');
      $ticket->phoneNumber= $request->input('phoneNumber');
      $ticket->regular_quantity= $request->input('regular_quantity');
      $ticket->vip_quantity= $request->input('vip_quantity');
      $ticket->event_id=$request->route('id');
      $ticket->total= $request->input('regular_quantity') + $request->input('vip_quantity');

      $event = Event::where('id',$ticket->event_id)->first();

     if($ticket->regular_quantity<$event->regular_attendies){
         if($event->regular_attendies>0){

        DB::table('events')->decrement('regular_attendies', $ticket->regular_quantity);
         }
         else{
             echo 'no tickets';
             return redirect ('/admin');

         }

     }
      elseif($ticket->vip_quantity<$event->vip_attendies){
        if($event->vip_attendies>0){
        DB::table('events')->decrement('vip_attendies', $ticket->vip_quantity);
        }  

       else{
           return redirect ('/admin');
       }  
    }
     $ticket->save();
      return redirect('/');
    }
```

Comment: which condition is failing, and have you tried dumping the actual values?

Comment: all of them.no i haven't

Comment: what does this give you. `var_dump($ticket->regular_quantity, $event->regular_attendies, $ticket->vip_quantity, $event->vip_attendies)`

Comment: string(1) "2" int(1) string(1) "2" int(4)

Comment: string(1) "2" int(1) string(1) "2" int(4) @Ghostff

Answer (score 1):

You've got a typo in the following part

```
elseif($ticket->vip_quantity<$event->$vip_attendies){
```

It should be this instead

```
} elseif ($ticket->vip_quantity < $event->vip_attendies) {
```

You accidentally added a `$` before the `vip_attendies`

## Update

Seeing as this did not fix your code, can a ticket only have `regular_quantity` or a `vip_quantity` or are both allowed. My guess would be that either of them is 0, an empty string or null. Which then messes up your redirect flow.

Comment: it still doesn't perfom as expected

Comment: @mimikiduchu Maybe edit your question to resolve it? Am still wondering how your code executed with that.

Comment: actually they has 0 but i've edited my code still not working

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if($ticket->regular_quantity<$event->regular_attendies)
```

To

```
if($ticket->regular_quantity<=$event->regular_attendies)
```

Also change

```
elseif($ticket->vip_quantity<$event->vip_attendies)
```

To

```
elseif($ticket->vip_quantity<=$event->vip_attendies)
```

When both of them are the same ignore everything and save the ticket anyway, with this you handle this